# How save GUID ID mongodb

Tags: c#, asp.net, mongodb, model-view-controller

I'm trying to save a `"guid id"` in mongodb, but when I save it, it saves as binary.
When you use a get, with even guid, it does not find.
How to save in the same `guid` format?

How I want you to save : `ownerId: "b0164f61-a203-478b-becc-b9a67312981d"`

How he saves: `ownerId: Binary('sBZPYaIDR4u+zLmmcxKYHQ==')`

> My ViewModel

```js
public class EmployeeViewModel
    {
        [BsonId]
        public Guid ownerId { get; set; }
        [BsonElement("personalData")]
        public PersonalDataViewModel personalData { get; set; }
        [BsonElement("address")]
        public AddressViewModel address { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: So you want to save it as a string?

Comment: Yes, can be. but I try save he as string, but he save as  binary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify the IdGenerator for BsonId.

```
public class EmployeeViewModel
    {
        [BsonId(IdGenerator=typeof(StringObjectIdGenerator))]
        public Guid ownerId { get; set; }
        [BsonElement("personalData")]
        public PersonalDataViewModel personalData { get; set; }
        [BsonElement("address")]
        public AddressViewModel address { get; set; }
}
```

https://codingcanvas.com/using-mongodb-_id-field-with-c-pocos/

Comment: worked perfectly, but remove "(" before  of IdGenerator.

Comment: Hello, because this change .net is accusing this error : Element 'Id' does not match any field or property of class. I need create new ask or you can help me ?